# Levi-Civita tensor in curved space

Tags: tensors, general-relativity

In the book "Gravitation and cosmology" by Weinberg at the page 99-100. He defines the Levi-Civita tensor as 
$\epsilon^{0123}=+1$ from which he writes

$\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}=g_{\mu\mu'}g_{\nu\nu'}g_{\rho\rho'}g_{\sigma\sigma'} \epsilon^{\mu'\nu'\rho'\sigma'}$

But he concludes that it gives
$\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}=-g \epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$

I don't understand the minus sign. If I consider the metric $g$ to be diagonal, we have

$\epsilon_{0123}=g_{00}g_{11}g_{22}g_{33} \epsilon^{0123}$ which gives
$\epsilon_{0123}=g \epsilon^{0123}$

Is it a typo in his book or is there something I don't understand ?

Comment: I can't remember completely but he may be using a different reference sequence?

Comment: Thx but what do you mean by a different reference sequence. He is using a signature $(+,+,+,-)$ and the order of coordinates is usually $(x,y,z,t)$

Comment: In the equation $\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} = -g\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$, what is $g$?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, $g$ is the determinant

Answer (score 1):

First consider the following:

$$ g_{\mu \mu'} g_{\nu \nu'} g_{\rho \rho'} g_{\sigma \sigma'} \varepsilon^{\mu' \nu' \rho' \sigma'} $$

It should be obvious from the definition of the determinant of a matrix that the following holds:

$$ g_{\mu \mu'} g_{\nu \nu'} g_{\rho \rho'} g_{\sigma \sigma'} \varepsilon^{\mu' \nu' \rho' \sigma'} \propto g \, \varepsilon_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}$$

We can now simply begin to compute the LHS to identify the constant of proportionality (choose $\mu = 0, \nu = 1, \rho = 2, \sigma = 3)$:

$$ g_{0 \mu'} g_{1 \nu'} g_{2 \rho'} g_{3 \sigma'} \varepsilon^{\mu' \nu' \sigma' \rho'}  \propto g \, \varepsilon_{0123}$$
$$ g_{00}g_{11}g_{22}g_{33} + \dots \propto -g$$

Hence, by recalling the explicit form of the determinant we must have that the proportionality constant is $-1$:

$$ g_{\mu \mu'} g_{\nu \nu'} g_{\rho \rho'} g_{\sigma \sigma'} \varepsilon^{\mu' \nu' \rho' \sigma'} = - g \, \varepsilon_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}$$